# Looks can be deceiving

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

Text version:

> I saw an "I", he said "it's L"
>
> I saw an "L", he said "it's V"
>
> I saw a "P", he said "it's Q"
>
> "Don't you get it?" he asked
>
> "Don't you see it?" I asked
>
> "No"  We both said

What is going on?

Comment: Why do you need the image version?

Comment: Long story. More for a decent visual effect.

Comment: This question feels really poetic!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you are looking at the shape of

> Braille letters and he is saying what these shapes actually stand for:
>
>  [image]
>
>  You don't get it as you don't know Braille, he doesn't see it as no vision. Thanks Beastly Gerbil!

Comment: I'm assuming as well that the other person is blind so thats why 'he cant see it'

Comment: Once again, very astute @Beastly Gerbil

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, good point and I added this explanation :)

Comment: @DEEM And you posted the puzzle as an image without text transcription, so that users with vision impairment can't read it. Very meta; we'll let it go this once ;-)

Comment: @Rand al'Thor. Complete ignorance on my part. If I put in the text will it be OK?

Comment: @DEEM I would recommend putting a text version in. It also means you'll fit the character requirement :P